# Find the Slope of the Tangent line with First Principle Method

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, tangent-line, slope

Given the function $y =\sqrt x-1$, determine the slope of the tangent when x = 10. You must find the slope of the tangent using the method first principles.

I know how to find slope of a function but not at a specific point. If you could help me out that'll be great.

Comment: Its second one I think.and the square root is of x-1

Comment: Yeah I got them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the slope we obtain:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt{10+h}-1-(\sqrt{10}-1)}{10+h-10}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sqrt{10+h}-\sqrt{10}}{h}=$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{10+h}+\sqrt{10})}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{10}}.$$